# Django: ValueError at/ "The view To_do_list_app.views.home didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Please, I am a newbie, if I didn't ask my question well, let me know.

I am working on a To-Do List app.

Anytime, I add a new task and time to the form on my web app and submit, I get the following error:

ValueError at /
The view To_do_list_app.views.home didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Below is my views.py file

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect

from .forms import ListForm
from .models import List

def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ListForm(request.POST or None )
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            act = List.objects.all
            context = {
                "act":act
            }
            return render(request,"home.html",context)
    else:
         act = List.objects.all
         context = {
              "act":act
         }
         return render(request,"home.html",context)
```

Here is also my forms.py file

```
from django import forms
from .models import List

class ListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = List
        fields = "__all__"
```

here is my models.py file

```
from django.db import models
class List(models.Model):
    activity = models.CharField(max_length=200,primary_key=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    time = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.activity
```

This is the home.html script(only the form html tag)

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0"   method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2"  type="text" placeholder="Add New 
     Task" name="activity">
     <input type = "datetime-local" name = "time" >
     <button class = "btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Add New Task</button>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fully integrated your code to my environment, carefully went trough your code and tested a few things. If you change the code of your views.py to the following, I think it will fix your problem:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ListForm
from .models import List


def index(request):
    act = ''
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ListForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            act = List.objects.all
            return render(request, 'myApp/home.html', {"act": act})
    else:
        act = List.objects.all
    return render(request, 'myApp/home.html', {"act": act})
```

resume: ( You had to make a global variable in the index-method ( or home method ) and set it to an empty string. Also you don't really need to use the context variable, you also can do it in the inline way, it will cost you less code. And last but not least you had to outdent the last return one time because that is the real return of the method. Otherwise the method only gives an if-structure with a return.. )

Comment: I just did it, I am getting this error: UnboundLocalError at /
local variable 'context' referenced before assignment

Comment: Okay, sorry about that. I didn't copy that section to stackoverflow properly.  They are are indented properly.

Comment: Can you edit your post so I can see the properly-indented code? If you do that it will be much easier to understand the reason you are getting the error.

Comment: Bro, please, don't be offended, my laptop battery is flat. When I get power, I will edit the code and let you know. Please be patient with me.

Comment: Don't worry, No problem, I understand.

Comment: See my edited answer, if it fixed your problem please mark it as accepted and vote it upwards :)

Comment: The problem is django is not validating the datetime field.when i removed the datetimefield from the models. there was no errors again. I need to write a custom model field for the datetime field. I have search the internet but i have not seen a detail guide on how to write a custom  model field.here is the source code of my project on github: https://github.com/coolpythoncodes/To_do_list

Comment: So you want to insert data in the database by the form with a datetime-local field, correct? If so, I think I can help you but it would be better if you asked this in another question because I think my code has solved your problem you wrote about in the title.. If it did, accept and vote it upwards and ask another question based on inserting data in a DateTimeField() in Django by using datetime-local.

Comment: I have cast the vote but my reputation is less than 15

Comment: Okay, then you should accept my answer by clicking on the check-icon below voting.