# ValueError at /addtodo/: Not able to add new items in todo-list

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4

I've tried to run this to-do app many times, first I wrote my own code, but it gave a lot of errors so I followed multiple tutorials, and read the documentation.

First, I tried to submit data using **html** forms only(i.e.without making a forms.py file), but it didn't return anything and just kept redirecting to my todo page; although I was able to add new items through the admin-site, but my form didn't return anything.
Second, I redid the entire project, removed the 'due_date' field (because it was causing problems) and created **ModelForm** in forms.py

I found out the main problem lies somewhere in my *views.py* file, with my **AddTodo** function.
I made changes in my function multiple times following instructions from [here](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-insert-data-into-a-database-from-an-HTML-form-in-Django.php), [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yXfUPwlZTw), and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovql0Ui3n_I)  when I was writing the views for html forms only.

In my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class TodoItem(models.Model):
    task = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task
```

In my forms.py file

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import TodoItem

class TodoItemForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta(object):
        model = TodoItem
        fields = ["task","category","description"]
```

In my project urls.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from todo_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('todo/',views.TodoView,name = 'todo'),
    path('addtodo/',views.AddTodo,name = 'addtodo'),
    path('deletetodo/<int:todo_id>/',views.DeleteTodo,name = 'deletetodo'),
]
```

In my index.html template

```
<div class="card-body">
    <p>Please fill the form to enter a new task:</p>
    
    <form action='/addtodo/' method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for="task">Task/To-do item</label>
            <input class = "form-control" type="text" id="task" placeholder="Add a new task">
        </div>
    
        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for="category">Category</label>
            <input class = "form-control"  type="text" id="category" placeholder="Give your task a label">
        </div>
    
        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for="description">Description</label>
            <textarea class = "form-control" id="description" rows="3" placeholder="Details of your task"></textarea>
         </div>
    
         <input class = 'btn btn-warning btn-lg' type="submit" value="Add">
     </form>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-8 d-none d-lg-block" id = 'task-list'>
    <h1>This is my ToDo List!</h1>

    <ul>
        {% for todo_items in all_items %}
            <li class = 'p-1 pl-3 mb-2' style="background: rgba(255, 255, 204,0.3); border-radius: 5px;" class="clearfix">
                <span class="float-left mr-5">{{ todo_items.task }}</span>

                <form action="/deletetodo/{{ todo_items.id }}/" class = "float-right mx-2" method="POST" style ="display: inline;">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="submit" class = 'btn btn-info btn-sm' value="Delete">
                </form>

                <span class="float-right p-1" style="background-color: rgba(204, 51, 255,0.7); border-radius: 5px;; font-size: small;">{{ todo_items.category }}</span>
                <br>
                <span style="font-size: small; color: rgb(255, 255, 102);"><strong>Details</strong> : {{ todo_items.description }}</span>

            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

And for my views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from todo_app.models import TodoItem
from todo_app.forms import TodoItemForm

# Create your views here.
def TodoView(request):
    all_todo_items = TodoItem.objects.all()
    return render(request,'index.html',{'all_items':all_todo_items})

def AddTodo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TodoItemForm(request.POST)
        all_todo_items = TodoItem.objects.all()
        if form.is_valid():
            new_item = form.save(commit = False)
            new_item.save()
        
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/todo/')

    else:
        all_todo_items = TodoItem.objects.all()
        form = TodoItemForm()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/todo/')

def DeleteTodo(request,todo_id):
    item_to_delete = TodoItem.objects.get(id=todo_id)
    item_to_delete.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/todo/')
```

If I comment out the *else* section in AddTodo i get

> ValueError at /addtodo/ The view todo_app.views.AddTodo didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

But with it, i'm only redirected to my todo page without having a new item in my list.

If i create views for simple html forms e.g.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    task = request.POST.get('task')
    category = request.POST.get('category')
    description = request.POST.get('description')
        
    new_item = TodoItem(task=task,category=category,description=description)
    new_item.save()
    
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/todo/')
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/todo/')
```

I get the same problem.

Kindly point out my mistakes, I'll really appreciate it.

Comment: i tried to follow the solution instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53632129/django-valueerror-at-the-view-to-do-list-app-views-home-didnt-return-an-http), and this [site](https://www.journaldev.com/22467/django-modelforms), but it didn't work out for me. It even stopped displaying the items i added from the admin site.

Comment: why are you hard-coded form fields manually and render form with `{{ form }}` tag in `index.html`? is it render only one of those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to render your template and pass it you form like in

```
return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

instead of redirecting.

Because that's what runs in the else (the GET, not the POST). You don't redirect the GET branch. Otherwise the template with the form is not rendered. You do that upon form submit success on the POST branch.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it much better now, all i did was remove the _else_ part and replaced **return HttpResponseRedirect('/todo/')** with **return render(request, 'index.html', {'all_items':all_todo_items,'form': form})**, and removed all the divs in my html form. that did it...the form generated by django was valid and todo items were being added to my list